# Working with ZoneFiles and I see odd domain names, are these encrypted?

Tags: dns, encryption

Are these domain names encrypted somehow?

```
0cvfk501t65vva2vmlb2oc5c1a48avm1.accountants
1247027g00qgaqi1d320mqqmdanvqm5m.accountants
162sbl7bmqhr2fll35jfghf3mvqvms83.accountants
7ho7ug4e67bbaq9cl6tmtkj0r03464in.accountants
```

I know DNS SEC is on the rise, so I want to assume they are, but if they are, how do I decrypt them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These look very much like NSEC3 hashed names. Those are based on your actual subdomains, but are only used for DNSSEC proofs of nonexistence, and don't have any other record types besides NSEC3 (and RRSIG).

It's probably possible to match each hash to its original name provided that you have access to the entire zone anyway, but apparently there are tools in the wild which just bruteforce the hashes blindly.

---

The earlier designs (NXT and NSEC) form a chain of plaintext domain names, e.g. `aaa.example.com` has the regular records plus a NSEC record pointing to `bbb.example.com`.

The signature of that record proves that there aren't any domains in between `aaa` and `bbb`, so the resolver can be sure that a NXDOMAIN reply is not fake. (Remember that one of the original DNSSEC goals was to allow offline signing of the zone, so that the servers could provide such proof without needing access to the signing keys.)

However, it's very simple to "walk" the entire chain from start to end, and learn all domain names even if you have disabled zone transfers. Some domain operators consider it a security problem. For that reason NSEC3 was invented which instead uses hashed names.

(Though pre-signed NSEC3 still has its own problems and might eventually be replaced with either NSEC3 "White lies" or NSEC5, both which seem to use a different approach involving individually signed responses.)